# W9 for French-US Freelancer Working in France but Contracting with US Companies

Tags: dual-citizenship, freelance

I am originally from France but have been living in the US for 13 years and now have dual citizenship. I am considering relocating back to France. I am a freelancer and I am looking at creating a "micro-entreprise" in France so I can continue my activities as an independent contractor. I would like to continue freelancing with some of my US-based clients. One of them said they would need an updated W9 with my new address so we can continue working together.

Can/Should I put my French address and my US Social Security number on a W9 form? To clarify, my client would wire payments to my French bank account, and I would pay my taxes in France (although I am aware that I would still need to file in the US every year).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As a US citizen, you are a US person, and should fill out W-9 instead of W-8BEN to provide your Social Security Number. You can put a foreign address on the W-9, as per the answer to [this question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/what-address-does-a-us-citizen-living-abroad-and-employed-as-a-consultant-by-a-f).